# Confused regarding ssh keys on linux

Tags: linux, ssh, key

I have few doubts regarding using private/public key on linux.

Suppose i have two linux boxes   `A` and `B`.

I want to use password less logins to `B` from any computer.

so on A i did this

`ssh-gen -t rsa` and it made two files

`id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

Then i copied `id_rsa.pub` to `B` `~/.ssh/A_id_rsa.pub` and then

`cat A_id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`

Now i have these questions

1. Suppose i have another computer `C` where i also want to have passwordless login but i want to use `key phrase` to protect the `private key`. so can i generate another key using `ssh-gen -t rsa` with different name and use that or i have to delete the previous key
2. The other thing is for password less logins do need to do anything with `keys` from `B` to `A` or its always from `A` to `B`
3. So the `private key` will always stay on host computer only? i have seen that AWS gives the private key for login. then why is that. Beuase for putting `A` public key to `B` someone needs to access `B`. which is not possible for first time. so does it mean we can login with either public key or private key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can generate a key pair on C and do the same that you did for A:

   cat C_id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
2. The keys will only allow logins from A to B.
3. Yes the private key will stay on the host computer. I believe AWS automatically puts the public key on computer B while it creates the virtual box.

Comment: can i delete the public key after appending to authorized_keys or it needs to be there. so it means we never need private key for anything beside being on host computer. if thats true then why system generates it

Comment: Yes, you can delete the public key after it is in authorized_keys, but I would keep it in case you want to reuse it on other machines. You need to understand that public key cryptography is based on the fact that the public key can be known by anyone, but is only useful if the private key is known. Since only computer A knows the private key, only computer A will be able to communicate with computer B, even if other computers have the public key. The private key must be kept secret for secure communication, hence it is called "private" key.

Comment: so it means if i copy private key of computer A to `C` then `C` can communicate with `B` ? Also i can have as many keys in .ssh folder with any names. but then how will the system knows which private key is for which public key

Comment: Yes, that is true, but there are dangers to doing so. Firstly, you need to be sure you copy the private key to computer C using a secure channel, like ssh or physically with a flash drive, never email, otherwise, there is the possibility the key will be compromised. Secondly, if you start spreading the private key to other computers as well, then if that key gets compromised on one machine, you need to replace the keys on all machines.

Comment: A good practice is, as you were mentioning in your original post, to encrypt the private key itself with a pass phrase. This adds another layer of security to your key and mitigates attacks.

Comment: But how will the system distinguishes which private key to use for which public key

Comment: If by "system", you mean computer A, there are a couple ways. `ssh -i privateKeyRSA user@host` or add the host to the ssh config file and point to the private key.

Comment: The ssh config file is in `~/.ssh/config` and should contain `Host hostIPAddress\n \t IdentityFile ~/.ssh/privateKeyRSA` where \n is newline and \t is tab character.

Comment: so umean if i have 5 different key pairs then i have to manually do above steps and system will not automatically do that

Comment: I believe there are some key manager programs out there that simplify the process a bit, but there is always some work, at least. I haven't used any such programs myself.

Comment: what is `known_hosts` and what are contents of it

Comment: Very basically, it stores the public keys of servers you have visited. If the public key changes, there is a good chance the server is compromised.

Answer (score 0):

In a quick line or two:

The keys somewhat work like (very roughly): you need the public key to decrypt what is encrypted by private key and vice-versa. To be more precise, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography has way better information to start with.

So to answer the questions: The private key is not normally tied to a computer. You could copy the private key from, say A to C and could login by using it from C.

You could generate multiple keys on a single host, one key-pair for each set of hosts. Similarly, you could generate keys from multiple hosts, each host publishing it's key to the target computer's (B in this example) 'authorized_keys' file.

Ideally, the private key should be as secret as possible. While the SSH or key-management would not force having the key on one computer, it should be limited to a single system as a best practice. Having said that, as far I know there is really nothing that prevents copying the private key around, say for backup or migration to a new system. In other words, the private key file is like the password, it could be literally used from any system to login.